# firebase token not generating

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-cloud-messaging-android/ to integrate firebase. I added every dependency and library to gradle and run the app. Unfortunately I m not getting token generated. No errors in logcat too. Ples advice. Here is my logcat.

```
01-07 18:31:29.306 14007-14007/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-07 18:31:29.792 14007-14007/jss.app I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is jss.app, real application class is android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication.

                                                          [ 01-07 18:31:29.821 14007:14007 W/         ]
                                                          Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
01-07 18:31:29.821 14007-14007/jss.app W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
01-07 18:32:57.251 14007-14007/jss.app I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
01-07 18:32:57.252 14007-14007/jss.app I/MultiDex: install
01-07 18:32:57.252 14007-14007/jss.app I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
01-07 18:32:57.417 14007-14007/jss.app D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-07 18:32:57.488 14007-14007/jss.app W/InstanceID/Rpc: Found 10010
01-07 18:32:57.522 14007-14007/jss.app D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
01-07 18:32:57.760 14007-14007/jss.app I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 10084
01-07 18:32:57.761 14007-14007/jss.app I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
01-07 18:32:57.761 14007-14007/jss.app D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
01-07 18:32:57.761 14007-14007/jss.app D/FA: AppMeasurement singleton hash: 155197368
01-07 18:32:57.802 14007-14007/jss.app V/FA: Collection enabled
01-07 18:32:57.803 14007-14007/jss.app V/FA: App package, google app id: jss.app, 1:681399697441:android:82aca32e9f5cdb7b
01-07 18:32:57.804 14007-14007/jss.app I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                    adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app jss.app
01-07 18:32:58.013 14007-14007/jss.app V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
01-07 18:32:58.017 14007-14007/jss.app I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
01-07 18:32:58.032 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: State of service unknown
01-07 18:32:58.033 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Checking service availability
01-07 18:32:58.069 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Service available
01-07 18:32:58.069 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Setting useService: true
01-07 18:32:58.072 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Using measurement service
01-07 18:32:58.084 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-07 18:32:58.224 14007-14007/jss.app V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-07 18:32:58.426 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Using measurement service
01-07 18:32:58.427 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 18:32:58.439 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 376491477
01-07 18:32:58.451 14007-14007/jss.app I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
01-07 18:32:58.464 14007-15110/jss.app D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-07 18:32:58.490 14007-14007/jss.app D/Atlas: Validating map...
01-07 18:32:58.499 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 72
01-07 18:32:58.499 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Using measurement service
01-07 18:32:58.499 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
01-07 18:32:58.500 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Activity paused, time: 376491549
01-07 18:32:58.582 14007-15110/jss.app I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: Nondeterministic_AU_msm8909_LA.BR.1.2.5_RB2__release_AU (I9d3821c5ab)
                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.04
                                                          Build Date: 02/24/16 Wed
                                                          Local Branch: mybranch18408715
                                                          Remote Branch: quic/LA.BR.1.2.5_rb2.32
                                                          Local Patches: NONE
                                                          Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
01-07 18:32:58.595 14007-15110/jss.app I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-07 18:32:58.638 14007-15110/jss.app D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-07 18:32:59.138 14007-15100/jss.app D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-07 18:32:59.138 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 3
01-07 18:33:00.504 14007-15109/jss.app I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:jss.app time:176343335
01-07 18:33:01.074 14007-14007/jss.app I/MultiDex: install
01-07 18:33:01.074 14007-14007/jss.app I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
01-07 18:33:01.362 14007-14007/jss.app W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-07 18:33:01.522 14007-14007/jss.app V/FA: onActivityCreated
01-07 18:33:01.962 14007-14007/jss.app I/CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.3.14.151
01-07 18:33:02.574 14007-15143/jss.app W/art: Verification of void com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.<clinit>() took 168.222ms
01-07 18:33:02.716 14007-15143/jss.app W/art: Verification of android.app.Dialog com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(int, android.app.Activity, int) took 116.429ms
01-07 18:33:02.725 14007-14022/jss.app I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41402(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 115(2MB) LOS objects, 60% free, 4MB/12MB, paused 10.249ms total 395.034ms
01-07 18:33:03.010 14007-15143/jss.app W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
01-07 18:33:03.019 14007-15143/jss.app W/ResourcesManager: Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
01-07 18:33:03.302 14007-14007/jss.app I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
01-07 18:33:03.472 14007-15150/jss.app I/System.out: Starting
01-07 18:33:03.799 14007-15152/jss.app I/System.out: Fixer Called
01-07 18:33:04.240 14007-14007/jss.app I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
01-07 18:33:04.390 14007-15150/jss.app W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
01-07 18:33:04.406 14007-14007/jss.app I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
01-07 18:33:04.417 14007-14007/jss.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 232 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-07 18:33:05.112 14007-15150/jss.app W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
01-07 18:33:05.178 14007-14007/jss.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-07 18:33:05.708 14007-15150/jss.app W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error
01-07 18:33:05.928 14007-14007/jss.app I/Choreographer: Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-07 18:33:06.052 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 376497391
01-07 18:33:06.052 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1712
01-07 18:33:06.066 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Activity paused, time: 376497917
01-07 18:33:06.067 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
01-07 18:33:06.162 14007-15100/jss.app I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
01-07 18:33:06.198 14007-15100/jss.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=1712, _sc=StartupActivity, _si=-5977363872906929719}]
01-07 18:33:06.345 14007-14007/jss.app I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3f826975 time:176349176
01-07 18:33:06.517 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Using measurement service
01-07 18:33:06.518 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Connecting to remote service
01-07 18:33:06.532 14007-15100/jss.app D/FA: Connected to remote service
01-07 18:33:06.532 14007-15100/jss.app V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
```

Comment: share you java classes code.

Answer (score 0):

It is done, the issue was with project. I created new project and added my app into it. Default project created for google drive was not working for fcm.